# Insert newline character after specific number of words

Tags: c#, string

I want to insert a new line character(\n) after 9 words in my string such that the string after the 9th word is in next line.

string newline="How to insert newline character after ninth word of(here) the string such that the remaining string is in next line"

Stucked here:

```
foreach (char x in newline)
{
    if (space < 8)
    {                    
        if (x == ' ')
        {
            space++;
        }
    }

}
```

Don't know why I got stucked. Its quite simple I know.
If possible, show any other simple method.

Thank you!

**Note: Found an answer for myself. Given by me below.**

Comment: The code you have included doesn't do what you say you are trying to accomplish, it only counts spaces. Please include the full code of your attempt. Also, please include a more detailed description of the errors/problems you are encountering so we may assist you better. Usually questions like this which ask us to "plz give me teh codez!" will get closed.

Answer (score 14):

For what it's worth, here's a LINQ one-liner:

```
string newline = "How to insert newline character after ninth word of(here) the string such that the remaining string is in next line";
string lines = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, newline.Split()
    .Select((word, index) => new { word, index})
    .GroupBy(x => x.index / 9)
    .Select(grp => string.Join(" ", grp.Select(x=> x.word))));
```

Result:

```
How to insert newline character after ninth word of(here)
the string such that the remaining string is in
next line
```

Comment: what if we need to insert two consecutive newline?

Comment: Then use `string.Join(Environment.NewLine+Environment.NewLine,...` instead

Answer (score 4):

This is one way:

```
List<String> _S = new List<String>();
var S = "Your Sentence".Split().ToList();
for (int i = 0; i < S.Count; i++) {
    _S.add(S[i]);
    if ((i%9)==0) { 
        _S.add("\r\n");       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use StringBuilder like:

```
string newline = "How to insert newline character after ninth word of(here) the string such that the remaining string is in next line";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(newline);
int spaces = 0;
int length = sb.Length;
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    if (sb[i] == ' ')
    {
        spaces++;
    }
    if (spaces == 9)
    {
        sb.Insert(i, Environment.NewLine);
        break;
        //spaces = 0; //if you want to insert new line after each 9 words
    }

}

string str = sb.ToString();
```

In your current code you are only incrementing your space counter but not comparing it with `9` and then inserting new line.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Environment.NewLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) inserting? You could also use the String.Split(" ") to get an array of all words btw...

Answer (score 0):

```
string modifiedLine="";
int spaces=0;
foreach (char value in newline)
{
    if (value == ' ')
    {
        spaces++;
        if (spaces == 9) //To insert \n after every 9th word: if((spaces%9)==0)
        {
            modifiedLine += "\n";
        }
        else
            modifiedLine += value;
    }
    else
    {
        modifiedLine += value;
    }                
}
```

Comment: This justs inserts one new line character after the 9th word and not after every 9th word, was that desired? Also, if i'd use a loop i'd use a `StringBuilder` instead of string concatenation which is less efficient.

Comment: for that we could have:

if((spaces%9)==0)